# How to make an Android App have a folder containing images on Installation?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make the app on installation have its own folder containing its own images which I would have added in the code, the images would probably be in the drawable, but I don't know how I can make selected images from drawable be in a folder of the application.

What I have tried so far:

*I have tried creating the folder but it's empty on installation and I added images to it normally but I can't get images from the drawable to the folder.

*Can I get a way to get images from the drawable into that folder or is there another way to create a folder and it should contain images that I would have selected via code.

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to create a `Bitmap` of the resource present in the `drawable` folder like,

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options() ;
options.inMutable = true ;
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources() , R.drawable.photo , options ) ;
```

Now, add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to the Android Manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

You need to request this permission from the user too. Once the permission is granted, simply save the `Bitmap` to a file,

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( imageFile ) ;
image.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100 , fileOutputStream ) ;
```

Comment: I have tried out your code but there's an error that keeps persisting. ```FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( imageFile ) ;``` I can't leave that line of code without the try/catch exception and when I do this error comes up ```Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException```